# Max date row using Talend Data Integration

Tags: json, csv, talend, maxdate

Using Talend Data Integration, following data is inputted from a CSV file

```
  Time       A          B          C
18:22.0 -0.30107087 3.79899955  6.52000999
18:23.5 -9.648633   0.84515321  1.50116444
18:25.0 -6.01184034 7.66982508  4.42568207
18:25.9 -9.22426033 3.12263751  5.10443783
18:26.7 -9.00698662 4.03901815  0.01316811
18:27.4 -4.31255579 6.25724602  5.02961922
18:28.2 -2.67013335 7.5932107   5.41628265
18:28.8 -1.76213241 6.26981592  7.44536877
18:29.5 -2.18590617 5.58567238  6.23928976
18:30.3 0.42078096  3.1429882   8.46290493
18:30.9 0.36391866  3.02926373  8.86752415
18:31.6 0.35673606  3.07176089  8.93396378
18:32.4 0.35374331  3.05081153  8.93994904
18:33.0 0.38187516  3.05799413  8.89745235
18:33.7 0.32920274  3.03644633  8.9315691
18:34.4 0.37529111  3.07475352  8.93575954
18:35.0 0.40342298  3.07654929  8.86393356
18:35.7 0.35254622  3.05260706  8.9267807
```

How do I extract only the max date row  (18:35.7    0.35254622  3.05260706  8.9267807) and load it into a JSON?

Comment: Have you had a look into the components *tFilterRow* (with a max parameter for `Time` then) and *tWriteJSONField*?

Comment: please tell me the date pattern??

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by sorting your file on the Time column (reverse alphanumeric sort gives the most recent Time on top), then take the first row and write it to a JSON file. Like so :
[image]

`tSampleRow_1` config :

[image]